# HTTP 500 error The localhost page isn’t working WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a new WordPress site but I don't know the cause why I'm getting an error in the second part of installation (Information Needed) where we have to put the site title, username, password and email.

HTTP 500 error The localhost page isn’t working

And so, I can't login on this site because the data is not saved on phpMyAdmin database.

All data is correct database name, username and password. I don't get why it has database kind of error. This is Apache error log:

```
[Wed Jan 18 14:55:15.767038 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1664] [client ::1:62560] WordPress database error Unknown column 'myslca_' in 'field list' for query SELECT myslca_, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.054742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\Requests\\Transport\\cURL.php on line 437, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.055742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.056742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   1. {main}() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-admin\\install.php:0, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.056742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   2. wp_install() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-admin\\install.php:375, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.057742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   3. wp_install_maybe_enable_pretty_permalinks() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-admin\\includes\\upgrade.php:94, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.058742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   4. wp_remote_get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-admin\\includes\\upgrade.php:340, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.059742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   5. WP_Http->get() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\http.php:170, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.059742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   6. WP_Http->request() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\class-http.php:593, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.060742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   7. Requests::request() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\class-http.php:366, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.061742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   8. Requests_Transport_cURL->request() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\class-requests.php:379, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.061742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP   9. curl_exec() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\Requests\\Transport\\cURL.php:162, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
[Wed Jan 18 14:56:13.062742 2017] [:error] [pid 10596:tid 1704] [client ::1:62576] PHP  10. Requests_Transport_cURL->stream_headers() C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sample-slca\\wp-includes\\Requests\\Transport\\cURL.php:162, referer: http://localhost:8020/sample-slca/wp-admin/install.php?language=en_US
```

Comment: Error 500 does **not** mean the server hasn't been started, that would be 408, request timeout. Error 500 is returned by the web server when the server is not correctly configured, or there is a script breaking error. On your file system in your WordPress directory, you will find an error log which will tell you your error. If you cannot find this file, then you can refer to the link below on how to enable debugging mode to display errors. You MUST disable debugging before you intend to have visitors to your site.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: @MichaelThompson There is no wp-config.php file yet before the installation.

Comment: That is true. I guess then his only option will be to look for the error log.
Under Apache (I am unsure of other servers such as nginx), usually there will be an error.log in your document root or the directory of the current running PHP script.

Comment: Hi so from your error log, I can see that you have MySQL errors and a PHP Timeout. Since you are currently in setup, it is safe to drop your database tables and start over. You also have a PHP timeout error, I would assume because cURL is attempting to download files that may be taking some time. You can safely increase your PHP max_execution_time from 30 seconds in php.ini as per this link:
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time
however I would encourage you to change it back once you are finished with the setup.